# Tkinter for loop, updating button text from a slider

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to learn for loops in Tkinter but struggling to find much information online. What I would like to happen is when the slider is altered the text within the label adjacent to it is updated live to the number shown on the slider. below is my current code. Thanks in advance for the help

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

def get(test):
    for i in range (6):
        Btns.config (text =scale.get())

for i in range (6):
    Btns = tk.Button(window, bg = "blue", width = 5, height = 1)
    Btns.grid (row = i, column = 5)

for i in range (6):
    scale = tk.Scale(window, orient = "horizontal", command = get)
    scale.grid (row = i, column = 6)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because all the widgets had been covered.Both of `Btn` and `scale` is the last `tk.Button` instance or `tk.Scale` instance.

You could use a list to save those widgets, and get those values by iterating:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()


def get(test):
    for i in range(6):
        Btns[i].config(text=scales[i].get())

# two list of widgets
Btns = []
scales = []

for i in range(6):
    Btn = tk.Button(window, bg="blue", width=5, height=1, text=0)
    Btns.append(Btn)
    Btn.grid(row=i, column=5)

for i in range(6):
    scale = tk.Scale(window, orient="horizontal", command=get)
    scales.append(scale)
    scale.grid(row=i, column=6)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it using `lambda`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

for i in range(6):
    btn = tk.Button(window, fg="white", bg="blue", width=5, height=1)
    btn.grid(row=i, column=5)
    scale = tk.Scale(window, orient="horizontal", command=lambda v,b=btn: b.config(text=v))
    scale.grid(row=i, column=6)

window.mainloop()
```